# Getting unexpected NoneType error in Python

Tags: python-3.x

While trying to create a minimal, reproducible example for another problem in Python 3.7.3, I ran into a NoneType Error that I wasn't expecting.

Main program:

```
import worker

def multiply_worker_value(arguments):
    current_Worker = arguments[0]
    multiplier = arguments[1]
    new_worker = current_Worker.change_value(multiplier)
    return new_worker

current_worker = worker.Worker()
print("Printing value:")
print(current_worker.get_value()[0])

while(current_worker.get_value()[0] < 10):
    paramList = [current_worker,2]
    current_worker = multiply_worker_value(paramList)
print(current_worker.get_value()[0])
```

Worker class:

```
import numpy
class Worker():
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = numpy.random.rand(10)
    def change_value(self,multiplier):
        self.values = numpy.sum(self.values*multiplier)
    def get_value(self):
        return self.values
```

When this is run, I get:

```
Printing value:
0.10619190084595542
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Visual Studio\repos\Projects2020\tests\concurrent_test\concurrent_test\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    while(current_worker.get_value()[0] < 10):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_value'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

and I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `while` loop, your `current_worker` gets overwritten with `None`:

```py
current_worker = multiply_worker_value(paramList)
```

this calls:

```py
new_worker = current_Worker.change_value(multiplier)
```

Your `Worker.change_value` method does not have a `return` statement, so it implicitly returns `None`.

Then, in the second iteration of your loop, your code tries to call `get_value` on `None`, which fails.